# How do I make a command a variable

Tags: bash, shell

A relative newbie here.
I'm reading in a file using the following commands:

```
while read line
 do 
      commands here
done < file
```

I'm splitting the line into two parts separated by a dash by the following

```
dash_pos=`expr index "$line" -`
```

`dash_pos` is obviously not a constant that's why I make it a variable.

I can now do the following

```
Part1=${line:0:$dash_pos -2}
Part2=${line:$dash_pos + 1}
```

These commands work as expected.

Is there a way that I can make the string manipulation commands a variable e.g

```
Find_Part1=${line:0:$dash_pos -2}
Find_Part2=${line:$dash_pos + 1}
```

so that

```
  Part1=$Find_Part1  &   Part2=$Find_Part2
```

work as before, but it will then allow me to do

```
 Part1=$Find_Part2   &   Part2=$Find_Part1
```

when necessary.

Any help will be appreciated as I have tried quotes, double quotes, brackets,
curly brackets and back ticks in a variety of combinations to try and get this
to work.
John

Comment: I have no clue what you are trying to achieve. Can you maybe add some sample input/output and functionality that you expect? I don't really see the point in switching variable names. Are you sure this is not an XY Problem: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem

Comment: You can, using `eval`, which should be pronounced "evil", because it is.  There is often a better way to do it than using evil, but I'm not sure why you want to do this.  Maybe consider using a function?

Comment: See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 ("I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but complex cases always fail!")

Comment: `Part1=$Find_Part1  &   Part2=$Find_Part2`. Why are you putting assignment commands into the background?

Comment: Hi Bernhard I am tagging a large number of mp3 files using track listing text files, some of which have Title - Artist, whilst other have Artist - Title. I was putting both parts into arrays, but needed to keep them in order when outputting to the files.

Comment: Hi cdarke I had tried to use eval as well, but failed there! Thanks for the the function idea.

Comment: Hi Charles, Many thanks, further along the link I found more than I needed.

Comment: Hi Kaz, I wasn't trying to put any assignment commands into the background, I just wanted the ability to swap, which I'll probably do by use of a function.

Comment: @John_S The `&` operator puts commands into a background process.

Answer (score 3):

Storing executable code in a variable is far more trouble than it is worth. Use functions instead:

```
Find_Part1 () {
    printf "%s" "${line:0:$dash_pos -2}"
}

Find_Part2 () {
    printf "%s" "${line:$dash_pos + 1}"
}

Part1=$(Find_Part1)
Part2=$(Find_Part2)
```

It appears, though, that what you really want is something along the lines of

```
while IFS="-" read Part1 Part2; do
   ...
done < file
```

to let the `read` command split `line` into `Part1` and `Part2` for you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I was trying to avoid using IF on every line of input. The text files will either be Title - Artist or Artist - Title completely so the question only needs to be answered once. John

Comment: How do you tell which lines start with the title and which start with the artist?

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear why you cannot just do what is literally in the question:

```
# get the parts
Find_Part1=${line:0:$dash_pos -2}
Find_Part2=${line:$dash_pos + 1}

# ... as necessary:

if such and such condition ; then
   Part1=$Find_Part1
   Part2-$Find_Part2
else
   Part1=$Find_Part2
   Part2=$Find_Part1
fi
```

Also, you can instead exchange the values of `Part1` and `Part2` when necessary, requiring only one temporary variable

```
if interesting condition ; then
    temp=$Part1; Part1=$Part2; Part2=$temp
fi
```

Inside a Bash function, we would might make `temp` a local to avoid name clashes and namespace clutter:

```
local temp
```

Comment: Hi Kaz, see above, but I will keep your idea. John